# inotify_init() function not implemented ERROR

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, system-calls, router, inotify

I am working on a Linux based router, I wrote code using `inotify_init()` for monitoring a file. The cross compilation was done without a warning or error message, but when I try to execute that code it shows an error like `function not implemented`

```
 if ( (fp = inotify_init()) < 0  ) {
    printf("something went wrong with inotify_init()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    printf("#### 1 can't open file\n");
    goto err; //exit(0);
}
```

Comment: What's your embedded linux kernel version? and the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel your system is using is missing the inotify functionality. Check your kernel config and make sure it is there.